# VestaCP - All domains point to the same website. Why?

Tags: http, nginx, digital-ocean, ubuntu-18.04, vesta

I have a bit of a problem. I setup several new domains on VestaCP, but they all point to the same default website. Part of the problem I guess is that all DNS records point to the same IP, but Vesta doesn't seem to know which website to take you to, so it takes you to a default website.

However, this problem only happens with HTTP, HTTPS forwards to the correct website. I don't know why. Is there a .conf somewhere that needs to be edited, or am I doing something wrong in VestaCP?

My setup is running on Digital Ocean -- Ubuntu 18.04, Nginx + php-fpm

Your help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Chceck if all DNS goes to IP of server with VestaCP. If yes, try look into `/home/yourloginname/web` Is there every your website? If yes, try to look to aliases. If you have subdomains, maybe head domain have alias *.domain.com .

And if your answer was no for some of questions above, try look into `/etc/bind/named.conf` where should have every domain 1 row for example:

`zone "domain.eu" {type master; file "/home/admin/conf/dns/domain.eu.db";};`

If not, add this one. Hope will be helpful.